# Saving html input value into a variable and sending that variable to a Flask endpoint

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I have a working solution to grab user input from my HTML and pass it to my Flask endpoint using request.form. However, the URL is not being built the way I'd like it to. Is there a way to grab user input and create a string out of it? For instance, instead of /summoner, have it be /summoner/whateverISearchedFor to appear in the URL of the browser.

HTML:

```
<form action="{{ url_for("getSummonerInformation") }}", method="POST">
    <input id="summonerSearched" name="summoner">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

My Flask endpoint:

```
@server.route("/summoner", methods=["POST"])
def getSummonerInformation():
    return request.form["summoner"]
```

I want something like this instead with a better URL:

```
@server.route("/summoner/<summoner_name>", methods=["POST"])
def getSummonerInformation(summoner_name):
    return summoner_name # I want to get the HTML without using request.form
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired outcome, you would have to change your request method and build the URL yourself. Because the input value is dynamic you would need to use JavaScript to get an url like `domainname.com/summoner/userInput`.

Another aproach would be to use a GET request instead of a POST request.Then you can access the query parameter with `request.args.get()` method. In this case you still need to use `request`. See more about [request arguments in FLASK documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args)

In your case:

HTML

```
<form action="{{ url_for("getSummonerInformation") }}", method="GET">
    <input id="summonerSearched" name="summoner">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Route def:

```
@server.route("/summoner")
def getSummonerInformation():
    summoner_name = request.args.get('summoner')
    return summoner_name
```